# Why is the connection to the database not made when page first loads?

Tags: jsf

I have a JSF 2.2 website app to schedule service appointments. The webpage uses a view Scoped bean, ScheduleBean. The ScheduleBean has the code to save the service appointments details, except the code to create the database connection. The code to create the database connection is in a separate bean, essentialQueryFunctions. ScheduleBean has essentialQueryFunctions as a managed bean, which it uses to return the database connection. The problem is that when the page first loads if you try to submit the service appointment it throws an error. ( I don't remember the error because I stopped using that webpage because of this issue.) However, if you load the page and then immediately refresh the page and then try to submit the appointment everything works well. So pretty much the server connection doesn't get made unless you refresh the page after it loads. I would like to add something else, I didn't include it because I didn't want to make the problem bigger, and they seem to be the same problem. There is a function that is supposed to trigger before the page loads which retrieves the available appointments times, but this function also doesn't trigger unless you refresh the page after it loads.

This is the scheduleBean

```
@ManagedBean(name="scheduleBean")
@ViewScoped
public class ScheduleBean
{
@ManagedProperty("#{essentialQueryFunctions}")
private EssentialQueryFunctions eQueries;

 public ScheduleBean()
  { 
    
  }

public void saveAppointment()
  {
    if (this.eQueries == null) {
      this.eQueries = new EssentialQueryFunctions();
    }
    PreparedStatement query = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet result = null;
    String subject;
    String body; 
    try
    {
      
        conn = this.eQueries.getDatabaseConnection();
      query = conn.prepareStatement("insert into guestAppointments(name, address, telephone, email, date, time, message) value(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
      
      query.setString(1, getName());
      query.setString(2, getAddress());
      query.setString(3, getPhone());
      query.setString(4,getEmail());
      query.setTimestamp(5, new Timestamp(getAppDate().getTime()));
      java.util.Date apTime = getDateTime(getAppTime());
      query.setTime(6, new Time(apTime.getTime()));
      query.setString(7, getMessage());
      query.executeUpdate();
      
    
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      setScheduleStep(2);
      Logger.getLogger(ScheduleBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    finally
    {
      this.eQueries.closeConnections(conn, query, result);
    }
  }// end of save appointment fucntion
}//end of bean
```

This is the code for the essentialQueryFunctions

```
public class EssentialQueryFunctions {
    @Resource(name="jdbc/mydb") 
    private DataSource source;
    public EssentialQueryFunctions(){
       
    }
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
         try{            
        Context ctx = (Context) new InitialContext();
        source = (DataSource) ((InitialContext) ctx).lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/mydb");
        }catch(Exception ex){            
        } 
    }
    
     public Connection getDatabaseConnection(){  
        Connection conn=null;   
        try { 
                conn=source.getConnection();
                return conn;
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                     Logger.getLogger(ScheduleBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    Logger.getLogger(ScheduleBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            return conn;        
    }
    public void closeConnections(Connection con, PreparedStatement statement, ResultSet result){
        closeResultSet(result);
    closePreparedStatement(statement);
      closeConnection(con);  
    }
    
    public void closeResultSet(ResultSet result){
      if (result != null) try { result.close(); } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ScheduleBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }  
    }
    
    public void closePreparedStatement(PreparedStatement statement){
     if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch (Exception  ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(ScheduleBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }   
    }
    
    public void closeConnection(Connection con){
      if (con != null) try { con.close(); } catch (Exception  ex){
    Logger.getLogger(ScheduleBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }  
    }
    
}
```

I don't know if you'll need it, but this is the website code

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{scheduleBean.scheduleStep eq 0}">
            
            <p class="avAppLabel"> Appointment Contact and Date/Time</p> 
            
        <hr/>
        <div class="appDetails">              
            <h:panelGrid columns="3" styleClass=" appContact" >            
                <h:outputLabel value="Name:"/>
                <h:inputText style="background-color: white;" value="#{scheduleBean.name}" id="first_input" required="true" maxlength="54"/>
            <h:message for="first_input"></h:message>
            
            <h:outputLabel value="Telephone:"/>
            <h:inputText style="background-color: white;" id="telephone_input" value="#{scheduleBean.phone}" required="true" maxlength="14"/>
            <h:message for="telephone_input"></h:message> 
            <h:outputLabel value="Address:"/>
            <h:inputText style="background-color: white;" id="street_input" value="#{scheduleBean.address}" required="true" maxlength="54"/>
            <h:message for="street_input"></h:message>
            
            <h:outputLabel value="Email:"/>
            <h:inputText style="background-color: white;" id="email" value="#{scheduleBean.email}" required="true" maxlength="254"/>
            <h:message for="email"></h:message>
                       
            <h:outputLabel/><h:outputLabel/><h:outputLabel/>     
            <h:message for="calendar"></h:message>            
        </h:panelGrid> 
        
            
            <p:calendar id="calendar"  styleClass="appCalendar"  value="#{scheduleBean.appDate}" disabledWeekends="true" required="true" mode="inline">
                <p:ajax process="@this" event="dateSelect" listener="#{scheduleBean.fillTimes()}" update="scheduleTime" />
            </p:calendar>
            
            
            
            
            <h:panelGrid class="timeSelection">  
                <h:outputLabel value="Select date to view Available Times:"/>
                <h:selectOneRadio value="#{scheduleBean.appTime}" id="scheduleTime" styleClass="scheduleTime" required="true">
                    
            <f:selectItems value="#{scheduleBean.scheduleTimes}"/>        
            </h:selectOneRadio> 
            <h:message for="scheduleTime"></h:message>
           
            </h:panelGrid>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        
        
        
        <div class="jobDetailsWrapper">
       
        
             <h:inputTextarea id="appMessage" styleClass="appMessage"  value="#{scheduleBean.message}" >
                 <f:validateLength maximum="254"></f:validateLength>
                 <f:ajax render="appMessage" listener="#{scheduleBean.clearMessage}"/>
             </h:inputTextarea>
             <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
          <h:commandButton styleClass="submitAppointment"  value="Submit Appointment" >
              <f:ajax event="click" execute=":appSubmit" listener="#{scheduleBean.saveAppointment}" render=":appConfirmation :appFail :appSubmit"/>
          </h:commandButton>
        </h:panelGroup>     
    </h:form>



<h:form id="appConfirmation">
    <h:panelGroup styleClass="appSuccess"  rendered="#{scheduleBean.scheduleStep eq 1}">
        <p>Your appointment has been successfully submitted.<br/><br/> A representative will contact you within 24 business hours to verify appointment. 
        <br/><br/></p>
        
        <h:commandButton value="Return to Scheduling" action="#{scheduleBean.reset}">
            <f:ajax render=":appConfirmation :appFail :appSubmit"/>
        </h:commandButton>        
    </h:panelGroup>
   </h:form>     
    
    <h:form id="appFail">
    <h:panelGroup  styleClass="appFail" rendered="#{scheduleBean.scheduleStep eq 2}">
        <p>Your appointment could not be submitted at this time. Please schedule by phone: 301-318-0797 and 703-622-8076. </p>
        
        <h:commandButton value="Return to Scheduling" action="#{scheduleBean.reset}">
            <f:ajax  render=":appFail :appConfirmation :appSubmit"/>
        </h:commandButton>
        
    </h:panelGroup> 
    </h:form>
    
                
            </h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Hey Mr. Balus, I see you updated my question as not being a JSF 2.x related question. Does this mean my issue is arising due to something unrelated to my code and I should look elsewhere? Thank you for taking the time to look at the question.

Comment: Is there any error thrrown? How does the program behave? Can you remove the irrelevant parts of your code (see [mcve])?